# cree mi tabla con "php artisan migrate" y luego "php artisan make:auth" en la base de datos me crea la tabla

Tags: laravel, model

como ven yo cree la tabla "user" en singular aproposito  y me quiero que se quede asi y de esta manera hacer todo el CRUD . pero laravel tiene una convencion. es decir me gustaria mantener mi tabla en singular, el modelo de la misma manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Porque quieres hacer eso? Tienes que cambiar el nombre de la migración users y colocarlo en singular.

Comment: Es debido a que no puedo tocar la estructura de la Base de Datos de un Sistema que me dieron a desarrollar, donde tiene una base de Datos y un M.E.R. sin normalizar ni nada ... una verdadera .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente en el modelo del usuario pones un atributo llamado `$table` para especificar manualmente un nombre de la tabla

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user';
}
```

El modelo por defecto del usuario se encuentra en `app\User.php`

Comment: gracias por la ... Respuesta .

Comment: @Rudy Si mi respuesta solucionó tu problema, por favor márcala como la respuesta aceptada para que así les sirva a otras personas :)